# How do I make a Class return a sting that is the size of the object dictated in the file?

Tags: java, class, object

## Problem:

I'm trying to make a rectangle using strings that would look like this

```
 ===
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
 ===
```

So far I've tried this text I want to appear in the console when I tell the program the width and height of the rectangle that I am able to get a rectangle like seen above. Is there an easier was to do this I'm still learning how to use Java. I'm more failure with javascripting.

### File: RectangleTester.java

```
    public class RectangleTester extends ConsoleProgram
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Create a new rectangle with a width of 10 and a height of 3
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 3);
        
        
            // Print out information about the rectangle
            System.out.println(rect);
        
            // Print out the area of the rectangle
            System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is " + rect.getArea());
        
            // Print out the height of the rectangle
            System.out.println("The height of the rectangle is " + rect.getHeight());
        }
    }
```

### File: Rectangle.java

```
    public class Rectangle
    {
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public String toString()
        {
            return makeTops() + makeSides() + makeTops();
        
        }

            

        
        public String makeTop()
        { 
                String tops = "==";

                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
                    tops += tops;
            }
        return tops;
        }
        
        private String makeSides(){
                String sideSpace =  sides + (space += space* (int)tops) + sides;
                String sides = "||";
                String space = " ";
            
                for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++){
                    sideSpace += sideSpace;
                
                }
                    
                return sideSpace;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, apart from maybe using `StringBuilder`, I don't see anything particularly wrong with what you're doing

Comment: @MadProgrammer the console is saying my issue is coming form Rectangle.java:29: error: cannot find symbol return makeTops() + makeSides() + makeTops(); –

Comment: Well, you have `makeTop()` in one place and `makeTops()` in some others.  You'll need to spell it consistently.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumstein It would also be useful to have you mention the "problem" you're having in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, `makeTops` is undefined...

```
public String toString()
{
    return makeTops() + makeSides() + makeTops();

}
```

You need to change `makeTop` to `makeTops`...

```
public String makeTops() { ... }
```

I have no idea of what's going on here...

```
private String makeSides() {
    String sideSpace = sides + (space += space * (int) tops) + sides;
    String sides = "||";
    String space = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        sideSpace += sideSpace;

    }

    return sideSpace;
}
```

You're trying to make use of variables which are not yet defined and you can't multiple a `String`, it doesn't make sense.

However, you can `repeat` a `String`...

```
private String makeSides() {
    String sides = "||";
    String space = " ";

    String line = sides + (space.repeat(width - (sides.length() * 2))) + sides;
    return (line + "\n").repeat(height - 2);
}
```

which also suggests you should change `makeTops` as well...

```
public String makeTops() {
    return "=".repeat(width) + "\n";
}
```

## Runnable example

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 3);

        // Print out information about the rectangle
        System.out.println(rect);
    }

    public class Rectangle {

        private int width;
        private int height;

        public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return makeTops() + makeSides() + makeTops();

        }

        public String makeTops() {
            return "=".repeat(width) + "\n";
        }

        private String makeSides() {
            String sides = "||";
            String space = " ";

            String line = sides + (space.repeat(width - (sides.length() * 2))) + sides;
            return (line + "\n").repeat(height - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Some, the above example will print...

```
==========
||      ||
==========
```

Now, before you tell me that's not `10x3`, it is, it's 10 columns, but 3 rows.

Now, if you wanted to display the "internal" area as the rectangle instead, you should change it to...

```
public class Rectangle {
    
    private static String SIDE = "||";
    private static String TOP = "=";
    private static String SPACE = " ";

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return makeTops() + makeSides() + makeTops();

    }

    public String makeTops() {
        return TOP.repeat(width + (SIDE.length() * 2)) + "\n";
    }

    private String makeSides() {
        String line = SIDE + (SPACE.repeat(width)) + SIDE;
        return (line + "\n").repeat(height);
    }
}
```

which will print...

```
==============
||          ||
||          ||
||          ||
==============
```